# Swapping JSON for Firebase

Tags: javascript, java, json, d3.js, firebase-realtime-database

I want to make a form for a live D3 sankey diagram [Link to source code here](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/c2637e28b79fb3bfea13) but I want to use firebase not JSON.

```
// load the data
d3.json("ConTech.json", function(error, graph) {

var nodeMap = {};
graph.nodes.forEach(function(x) { nodeMap[x.name] = x; });
graph.links = graph.links.map(function(x) {
  return {
    source: nodeMap[x.source],
    target: nodeMap[x.target],
    value: x.value
  };
});

sankey
  .nodes(graph.nodes)
  .links(graph.links)
  .layout(32);
```

The above is what I need to edit to refer to my firebase database.

This is my data from my form in firebase
[image]

This is my attempt to extract the data into an array and seems to give me what I need.

```
function gotData(data) {
//console.log(data.val());
var links = data.val();
var nodes = data.val()
var lkeys = Object.keys(links);
var nkeys = Object.keys(nodes);
//console.log(keys);
for (var i = 0; i < lkeys.length; i++) {
  var k = lkeys[i];
  var source = links[k].source;
  var target = links[k].target;
  if (source !== undefined){
      slist.push(source);
    }
    if (target !== undefined){
      tlist.push(target);
    }
//console.log(source, target);
}
for (var x = 0; x < nkeys.length; x++) {
    var kn = nkeys[x];
    var name = nodes[kn].name;
    if (name !== undefined){
      nlist.push(name);
    }
//console.log(name);
}
//console.log(slist, tlist, nlist);
//console.log(source, target, name);
}
function errData(err) {
    console.log('broke!');
    console.log('err');
}

function getData () {
  console.log(slist, tlist, nlist);
}
```

However im struggling to swap

"d3.json("ConTech.json", function(error, graph)"

for the right implementaiton.